# Access seperate plots generated in a for-loop(matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have multiple graphs to compare to each other but it is very time consuming to compare the graphs then change the code to compare the next features. Thats why i decided to use buttons to show and hide the plots I need.
The graphs are computed in a for-loop because of the uncertain number of plots to show simultaniously. This is done in a fashion showed at the bottom. 
**The problem is that i can't access the plots inside the for-loop to switch them on.So I need three buttons total, one for every function.**

```
for f in flist:
    ax1.plot(f['x'], f['fx'], label=f['fname'] )
ax1.legend()
```

In the part above I generate the plots and in the following part I have to access the plots and labelnames

```
lines = [ax1]
```

But that doesn't work like I thougt. Do you have any suggestions how I could solve the problem?
I've got the code from a matplotlib example ([See Check Buttons example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/widgets/check_buttons.html#sphx-glr-gallery-widgets-check-buttons-py)). Shown below is a code example the way I want to use it and doesn't work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons

flist = []
xl = [np.linspace(0,8,265)]

for xi in xl:
    flist.append({'x': xi, 'fx': -0.4*(xi-4)**2+3,'fname':'-0.4*(xi-4)**2+3'})
    flist.append({'x': xi, 'fx': -0.4 * (xi - 5) ** 2 + 3, 'fname': ' -0.4*(xi-5)**2+3'})
    flist.append({'x': xi, 'fx': -0.4 * (xi - 3.5) ** 2 + 3, 'fname': '-0.4*(xi-3.5)**2+3'})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
gs = GridSpec(2, 2, width_ratios=[1, 2.5])

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[:, :-1])
for f in flist:
    ax1.plot(f['x'], f['fx'], label=f['fname'] )
ax1.legend()
ax1.set_xlabel("time")
ax1.set_ylabel("amplitude")
ax1.set_title('graphs')

lines = [ax1]

# Make checkbuttons with all plotted lines with correct visibility
rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])
labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in lines]
visibility = [line.get_visible() for line in lines]
check = CheckButtons(rax, labels, visibility)

def func(label):
    index = labels.index(label)
    lines[index].set_visible(not lines[index].get_visible())
    plt.draw()
check.on_clicked(func)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lines` should be a list of lines you want to toggle visibility for. Hence you would want to fill this list with the lines in the for loop.

```
lines = []
for f in flist:
    line, = ax1.plot(... )
    lines.append(line)
```